# Include multi-selection option in file-open-dialog

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria

To allow multiselection in a file-open-dialog and to avoid this long expression:

```
OpenDialogSourceFiles.Options := OpenDialogSourceFiles.Options + [Vcl.Dialogs.fdoAllowMultiSelect]; // works
```

I tried to use the shorter `Include` function:

```
System.Include(OpenDialogSourceFiles.Options, Vcl.Dialogs.fdoAllowMultiSelect);  // error
```

However, the compiler marks this as erroneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. The `Include` procedure requires a variable as its first argument (it is a `var` parameter, essentially, even though the procedure is implemented by compiler magic), but `TFileOpenDialog.Options` is a property.

Hence you must use the verbose alternative. There's nothing you can do about it.

The same thing applies to `Inc` and `TComponent.Tag`, for instance.

(But you can write `fdoAllowMultiSelect` instead of `Vcl.Dialogs.fdoAllowMultiSelect`, `Include` instead of `System.Include`, etc. to make it a bit less verbose.)

Comment: But when I try to declare the open-dialog options as a variable: `var DialogOptions: TFileOpenDialog.Options;` ...this also creates an error.

Comment: Yes. In `var X: T`, `T` must be a *type*. What you can do: `var X := MyFileDialog.Options; Include(X, fdoAllowMultiSelect); MyFileDialog.Options := X`.

Comment: Of course, there is an easier solution. Just enable the flag at design-time instead, and then you don't have to worry about setting it in code at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I could not have thought of it myself ;) There are different situations: One where multiselection should be allowed and another where multiselection is not allowed. That's the reason why I do it programmatically.

Comment: @user1580348 sure, you could do it that way. You will just have to live with the coding syntax required, as Andreas showed. Or, you could just use 2 separate `TFileOpenDialogs` with different configurations. That would work, too.

Comment: I don't like adding UNNECESSARY COMPLEXITY by using two separate TFileOpenDialogs with different configurations.

Comment: Increasing the complexity by using two different OpenDialog components would only make sense if the OpenDialog options differ significantly in the two situations. Currently, the two situations differ only by the usage of the MultiSelection option.